# Rails PUT/POST request fails on first try, works on next

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a VueJS Frontend application with a Ruby On Rails API backend. I need to change information about a user in the database.

I have a PUT/POST request that removes the creditcard information. The basic rails code is below. The issue I am having is that I get the, very popular, error:

`NoMethodError (undefined method []' for nil:NilClass):`

But the catch is that it only happens on the **first** attempt. Subsequent attemps are successful. Can someone point me in the right direction here? Should you need additional informaiton, please don't hesitate to ask.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :load_account, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :formats, :charges, :destroy_card]
   
   def destroy_card
     @account.card_last_4 = nil
     @account.card_type = nil
     @account.card_exp_month = nil
     @account.card_exp_year = nil
     @account.plan_id = 1
     @account.save!

     render json: { account: @account }, status: 200
   end

   private

   def load_account
     if @current_user.admin?
       @account =  Account.find(params[:id])
     else
       @account = @current_user.accounts.find_by_id(params[:id]) unless @account.present?
     end
   end
 end
```

Errors:

```
Started PUT "//accounts/20/destroy_card" for ::1 at 2020-08-17 20:24:47 -0400
Processing by AccountsController#destroy_card as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>20, "account_id"=>"20"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `load_user'
  AccountUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `account_users`.* FROM `account_users` WHERE `account_users`.`user_id` = 10 AND `account_users`.`account_id` = 20 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `load_user'
  Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 20 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:30:in `load_user'
  CACHE Account Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 20 LIMIT 1  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:97:in `load_account'
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/account.rb:148:in `assign_plan'
  Plan Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `plans`.* FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/account.rb:148:in `assign_plan'
  Account Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE `accounts` SET `accounts`.`card_last_4` = NULL, `accounts`.`card_type` = NULL, `accounts`.`card_exp_month` = NULL, `accounts`.`card_exp_year` = NULL, `accounts`.`plan_id` = 1, `accounts`.`updated_at` = '2020-08-18 00:24:47' WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 20
  ↳ app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:82:in `destroy_card'
  Account Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE `accounts` SET `accounts`.`plan_updated_at` = '2020-08-18 00:24:47' WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 20
  ↳ app/models/account.rb:60:in `stripe_subscribe'
   (9.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:82:in `destroy_card'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1150ms (ActiveRecord: 10.4ms | Allocations: 22601)



NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/models/account.rb:71:in `stripe_subscribe'
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:82:in `destroy_card'
```

Code from `account.rb`

```
 def stripe_subscribe
    s = stripe_customer.subscriptions.first

    self.plan_updated_at = Time.now
    save!

    if coupon.present? && plan.id != coupon.plan_id
      self.coupon = nil
      save!
    end

    if plan.price == 0
      # Downgrading from a paid tier
      if s.present?
        meta = s.delete
        self.changed_plan = Plan.find(previous_changes[:plan_id][0])
        self.changed_plan_date = Time.at(meta['current_period_end']).to_datetime
        save!
      end
    else
      s.delete({ prorate: true, invoice_now: true }) if s.present?
      params = { items: [{ plan: plan.short_name }] }
      if coupon.present?
        params[:coupon] = coupon.token
      end
      stripe_customer.subscriptions.create(params)
      if Rails.env == 'production'
        client = Slack::Web::Client.new
        client.chat_postMessage(channel: '#somechannel', text: "some random message", as_user: true)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: If it's possible, plz upload rails log of full request that contains errors you encounter.

Comment: @NinhLe this is done!

Comment: app/models/account.rb:71 can you upload  code contained in this file, maybe method its name is `stripe_subscribe`

Comment: maybe this code: `@account = @current_user.accounts.find_by_id(params[:id]) unless @account.present?` return nil so @account variable is not defined. Also use find instead of find_by_id

Comment: @NinhLe this is done

Comment: I guess `previous_changes[:plan_id][0]` may cause the error, but I'm not sure. So I recommend you using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), puts a breakpoint in `stripe_subscribe` method, run code line by line you will find the bug

Comment: @NinhLe Yes you are right, this is what was causing the issue.

Comment: Just a suggestion: as per the code in `#destroy_card` it would be meaningful to name it as `#nullify_card` :)